# iframe tag and object tag loads black pages

Tags: html, iframe

Some webpages load with the object/iframe tag but then when i try to load a page like google it fails and gives me a black page. Do websites like google have a way to block object/iframe loads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
<script>
if (top.location !== self.location) {           //If page is inside an iFrame
    //top.location = self.location;
    //Do anything you want
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do that for security reasons..

**offtopic** I don't know why you used the `html5` tag for a question about iframes..